# Process Builder - Insert Criteria

Tags: process-builder

How do I set up criteria in Process Builder to detect `Insert`? I have tried setting Field to `Id` and Filter to `IsChanged`, `WasSet`, and `IsNull`, all to no avail. I want a process to take one action when a record is inserted, and make sure all subsequent criteria apply only on update.

Is this issue perhaps because I am trying to detect a change from null? I found [this discussion](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DgM9AAK) on the Ideas Exchange that may be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Process Builder supports ISNEW  and ISCHANGED

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_advanced_considerations.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 2):

I use field `LastModifiedDate`, filter `isChanged`, value `false`. The only time this can ever be true is when the record is inserted, because the old value is null.